# Algorithm for searching "unstructured" dataset (of parameters and values)

Tags: algorithm, search, matching, fuzzy-search

Given an unstructured dataset consisting of sets of various parameters with numeric quantities, what's an efficient and practical algorithm for searching? The parameters vary wildly, with no exhaustive list of parameters, and any parameter can be part of any set.

That was either a very good problem description, or just confusing. So let me try an example:

```
"dataset" : [
{"a": 4, "b": 1},
{"a": 4, "b": 1, "c": 0.5},
{"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 0.5, "x": 1},
{"x": 3, "t": 0.01}
]
```

search input (to match/score against dataset):

```
q = {"a": 2, "b": 1}
```

I'm thinking a matching/scoring rule along the lines of:

for each "set", `s`, in the dataset, scan through the parameters of `s`. If `q` contains same parameter (name/key), then let `v` be the quantity (value) of that parameter in `s`. Let `w` be corresponding value in `q`, and this parameter is scored, `max(w/v, 1.0)`.

Repeat for each parameter of `s`, producing an overall score (of  as the product of all the "sub scores").

So, `q` scores 
2/4 * 1/1 = 0.5 against the two first sets, 0.33 against the third set, and 0 against the last one. I'm not sure how to handle parameters in `s` that are *not* in `q`, but maybe those could give some secondary score (for those "hits" where `score > 0`).

Any tips on what to search (google) for here, any well-suited algorithms on something like this?

Comment: Well, you have described the problem and your algorithm. Any code ?

Comment: No, this is only at the idea stage so far. It occurs to me this might be similar to a matching algorithm used in a dating site, where people are scored according to matching interests etc? Maybe this is suitable for some optimization approach?